# fread() behaves weird

Tags: c, fread

I have a problem in a C program of mine where after I use `fread()`, the file pointer goes to the end of the file sometimes.

I'll try to explain better - the code looks something like:

```
dummy = ftell(fp);
fread(&buf, sizeof(unsigned char), 8, fp);
dummy = ftell(fp);
```

where `fp` is a file pointer to an opened file (opened it with "w+", I'm using it as a binary file and I know i'm supposed to have a "b" in there too, but I heard its not really important to add it..),
`dummy` is just an `unsigned long` variable,
and `buf` is `unsigned char[8]`

now, when debugging, at the `ftell` before the `fread`, `dummy` is 262062
at the `ftell` after the `fread`, `dummy` is 262640
even though I only 'moved' 8 bytes..

does anyone have any idea what can be the cause of this..?
thanks for your help :)

Comment: The "b" in your fopen is needed on some platforms (MS Windows, for example), but it shouldn't matter for the problem you're seeing.

You said that buf "unsigned char buf[8]" but you're passing it as &buf.  That's not right.  Either you're passing the address of a pointer that points to those bytes or you're passing garbage that results from a bug in your compiler not catching that you aren't supposed to be able to take the address of a literal value.  If it's the first, then you must have a pointer set to the address of where you actually declared your array.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't use the `b` to open the file, `ftell()` doesn't return the truth, just a sort of "cookie" that's only useful to `fseek()`.  There are a lot of different implementations out there; check the man page for your system to find out more.